# Karate API Testing - Converting from JSON array to String

Tags: karate

I need to read an id from a `GET` request and use that in `POST` for performing a test. The id that I retrieve from GET is in the form of array from the following expression:

```
And def reqId =  response.teams[*].resource[1].resourceRequestId

`["59aeb24be4b0b17227553d07"]`
```

I store this Id as variable:

```
And def reqId =  response.teams[*].resource[1].resourceRequestId
```

When I use this in my `POST` operation, I get the following error:

```
exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token\n
```

Is there a way I can perform JSON.stringify() etc to convert the value to a string or a way to extract it and use it more purposefully in `POST` request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending an array instead of a single string. Keep in mind that the moment you use `[*]` in a JsonPath, the result is always an array.

```
And def temp =  response.teams[*].resource[1].resourceRequestId
And def reqId = temp[0]
```

Now try, it should work. We are introducing a `get[0]` syntax convenience to make this cleaner in the next version. Look out for it.